# Using `_path` in Rails Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm currently working with a mailer in which I need to link an `index` view.  In my app, this is reachable by `reminders_path`, but when I used that in my mailer (`<%= link_to "Memory Enhancer", reminders_path %>`) the link didn't work.

After some googling and some SO searches, most things seemed to recommend something like this:

```
<%= link_to "Take Me To My Memory Enhancer", Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(controller: "reminders", action: "index") %>
```

However, the link still isn't functional.  What is the "proper" rails way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `reminders_url`, as you want a full url, not just the path.

Comment: Gah!  Thank you!  Why was that nowhere on the internet?